# Chrome Extension Permissions on Click (by default)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm making a Chrome extension, and I would like it to have site access "On Click" by default.

Picture of site access section:
[image]

When I install my extension, I have to set this manually rather than this being the default. The reason I want this is that my extension is meant to be used on sites with mostly static content.

(I'm aware of work-arounds, like having my extension scripts fire only when I click the extension icon, but that seems unnecessarily complicated.)

Comment: Please user [optional_host_permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/#step-2-declare-optional-permissions-in-the-manifest);

Comment: You can simply use the [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission.

Comment: Made those changes, but it didn't work -- my extension still runs on all sites without being clicked.

I added
  "optional_permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "downloads", "activeTab", "scripting"],
to my manifest.

(The other permissions are needed for the rest of my code to run)